# Json parsing through glob in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a bunch of  json files in the remote server as below. The code is not printing any data with this script. What is the issue?

```
import json
import glob
for files in glob.glob('//remoteserver IP/folder1/folder2/file-en-us_US*.json'):
        with open(files) as json_data:
             data = json.load(json_data)
             print data['header']['groupType']
```

Answer (score 1):

Since nothing is being printed rather than a `ValueError` while parsing JSON or a `KeyError` while referencing the data, your `glob.glob` call is likely returning an empty list.

Comment: How can i get the resulting values. All the files have groupType as "P" or "F"

Comment: Arun, I think Ben is telling you that you need to find out what's wrong with the expression you're passing to `glob`, ie, the way you're telling it what files you want to process.

Comment: Maybe just try an `os.listdir` on the directory you want to find the files in to see if the remote share can even be treated like a normal path in Python.

Comment: This leads me to a doubt whether glob.glob() really can connect to the remote server and parse the json files.Do i need to use paramiko module to establish the connection and use glob.glob()

Comment: If you can `open` or `os.listdir` using a path that is on a shared folder, the issue must be your `glob` pattern.